# iBook G4 stuck in blue screen

Tags: mac, boot, g4, ibook

Won't boot into safe mode. I tried booting it holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> but it doesn't work! it gets to blue screen and its stuck. I managed to get it passed there by sheer luck once but thats it.

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Answer (score 1):

- Hold down the Option key - does it enter the boot disk chooser screen?
- Put the OS install CD in the drive, and boot holding down the C key. Does that work? If so, use Disk Utility to run a scan on the drive.
- Can you plug in an external monitor? What happens when you do?

Answer (score 0):

## It's Bricked

I don't remember a blue screen, but I had one that did the grey screen and wouldn't enter the loader. Could be a a variety of hardware issues or even software issues. Take it to an Apple store for the best diagnosis.

Comment: it gets passed the apple logo and the ajax spinner gif. If that helps any for you to diagnose. We do not have any apple stores in turkey...

Comment: @Sevki: Have you tried the boot loader? Hold down `option`.